# How to prove exactness implies complex?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In an abelian category, there are notions of exact sequence and complex. Since the objects there may not be abelian groups, the definition of exact sequence and complex are all complicated. And the trivial fact that every exact sequence is a complex for abelian groups and modules are not trivial here. How to prove this fact in an abelian category?

Comment: Maybe you can say a little more about what your difficulty is. (For instance, I do not understand why you say that the definition of "complex" is more complicated in an aribtrary abelian category.) A good start might be to write down exactly the definitions of "complex" and "exact" that you are using for an arbitrary abelian category.

Comment: The point is that the definition of kernel and cokernel in such category is complicated, as well as image(:= kernel of cokernel). But now I seem to know how to prove this, it is really not very obvious. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean now. It's true that it takes some practice to be able to relate element-theoretic conditions and arrow-theoretic ones. If you have a solution, maybe you should write it as an answer, in case anyone has the same problem in future.

Comment: But this is difficult here, since the answer involves quite a few arrows and is not easy to exhibit here. The main point is to write each morphism as an composite of two, in two different manners, just as in the group theory, one involves a map to image(this is essentially the original map) and an inclusion, the other involves a map to cokernel and then the induced map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the definition you are using?

Consider two morphisms $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} Z$. The image of $f$ is defined to be the kernel of the cokernel of $f$, and the sequence is exact at $Y$ if that is also the kernel of $g$. In detail, let $Y \xrightarrow{c} C$ be a cokernel of $f$, and let $K \xrightarrow{k} Y$ be the kernel of $c$; then the sequence is called exact at $Y$ if the map $k$ is also a kernel of $g$.

What you are asking about is how to prove that if $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} Z$ is exact at $Y$ then $gf=0$. Let's see: we have $cf=0$, so by the universal property of the kernel of $c$, there is a morphism $X \xrightarrow{u} K$ such that $f = ku$. Therefore $gf=gku$ which is $0$ since we are assuming $k$ is also a kernel of $g$.

Comment: Right, this is exactly my problem, and I know how to prove now. Thank you!